# getting length of array which is itself an element in a list

Tags: python, arrays

new to Python. I figure this is a pretty basic question but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm trying to find the length of a list, however using len(variable) always returns 1, not the size of the list itself. So for the variable prz:

```
    print type(prz)
    print prz
    print len(prz)
```

outputs:

```
    <type 'list'>
    [array([2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2])]
    1
```

what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I created prz in this way:

```
prz = []
prz.append(np.random.randint(0, 5, nsim))
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you create prz? Its a list with 1 item... an array. Try `print prz[0]` to see what i mean.

Comment: The list contains one element, an array object (which contains its own elements separate from the list it happens to be in).

Comment: is there a method I can use to access the array in the object?

Comment: yes, `prz[0]` is the array.

Comment: if you wanted item 3 in the array, it would be `prz[0][2]` (counting from zero...)

Comment: Why did you make a 1-element list? `prz` seems entirely pointless; you could use the result of the `randint` call directly.

Comment: I edited the title of the question to more clearly reflect the actual problem (finding the length of an array which is itself the element of a list).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, your list contains one element which happens to be an`array`object (which is similar to a`list`, but not exactly the same). If you know the index of the element in the list, and you know it's something with a length (like an `array`), then you can find its length by calling the built in`len()`function on it:

```
from array import array

prz = [array('i', [2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2])]

print len(prz)     # -> 1
print len(prz[0])  # -> 10
```

This should work for numpy arrays, too.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer...

prz is a list with a numpy array as a member. You get the array by indexing prz, and you can also get the array members with a second level of indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> nsim = 10
>>> prz = []
>>> prz.append(np.random.randint(0, 5, nsim))
>>> prz
[array([4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 0])]
>>> prz[0]
array([4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 0])
>>> prz[0][0]
4
```